# How can i hide next set of elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide the `<tr>` elements which are not having class in between the `<tr>` which has class 'class1'

```
   <tr class="class1"><td><input type="button" value="Click" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>6</td></tr>
   <tr class="class1"><td><input type="button" value="Click" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>7</td></tr>
   <tr><td>8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>9</td></tr>
   <tr><td>10</td></tr>
   <tr><td>11</td></tr>
   <tr><td>12</td></tr>
   <tr class="class1"><td><input type="button" value="Click" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>7</td></tr>
   ...etc
```

When I click the `<tr class="class1">`, the code should hide only `<tr>` which are between the clicked row - and the next one with class 'class1'.

Comment: You want to hide elements which are not having class  =  class1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want the [JQUery `nextUntil()` function](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/), something like the following:

```
$(".class1").click( function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".class1").hide();
} );
```

```js
$(".class1").click( function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".class1").toggle();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> <tr class="class1"><td><input type="button" value="Click" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>6</td></tr>
   <tr class="class1"><td><input type="button" value="Click" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>7</td></tr>
   <tr><td>8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>9</td></tr>
   <tr><td>10</td></tr>
   <tr><td>11</td></tr>
   <tr><td>12</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
 $("tr.class1").click(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil(".class1").hide();
   });
```

- First make a click handler for .class1 tr
- than select all tr until(before) .class1
- hide them all

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide between tr  clicked class try

```
$(".class1").click( function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".class1").hide();  //hide next class with name class class1
    $(this).prevUntil(".class1").hide();  //hide previous class with name class class1
} );
```